# Style Library has permission issues SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, office365

I am site administrator but when I am uploading or creating something under style library, it is giving error permission denied. The permission on library is inherited from site while I am also in owner group. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ali Murtaza,

This should be caused by [NoScript setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252f1F2C515F-5D7E-448A-9FD7-835DA935584F) of Modern Sites. Please try below cmdlets to fix it:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenantname>-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<SiteUrl> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

more about SharePoint Online Management shell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps) and download the SharePoint Online Management Shell [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588).

BR